# Capistrano current pointing to latest release but error is being shown from old release

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, capistrano

I have been deploying my `rails` application with `capistrano`. `cap deploy` command works fine. Symlink points to latest release..

```
/var/www/my_app/current -> /var/www/my_app/releases/20141105160254
```

But when I browse to application, I am getting error from previous release..

```
Validation failed: Email has already been taken

Rails.root: /var/www/my_app/releases/20141031155640
```

Any idea, how to fix this?

Comment: It's not Nginx problem. Have you reloaded backend (unicorn/passenger/?) after deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Rails didn't restart properly. Did you see errors in the Rails restart instruction in the Capistrano logs?

You should either force Rails to restart:

```
touch /var/www/my_app/current/tmp/restart.txt
```

or restart your web server. For instance, with Apache2:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```